# Space is direct sum of subspaces - propostion conditions giving me problems

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, direct-sum

In Sheldon Axler's *"Linear Algebra Done Right" - 2$^{\textrm{nd}}$ Edition*, on the section for **Direct Sums**, the following proposition is stated.

---

[image]

---

Following this is the proof of this 'if and only if' proposition - first in the forward direction ($V=U_1 \oplus \cdots \oplus U_n \,\implies \,$ (a) & (b) ). This is the part I am having trouble understanding.

---

[image]

---

**Here is my problem:** To prove (b), the author seemed to simply use (b), thus proving it using itself, which is a tautology! How can the author say *"Then each $u_j$ must be 0*, and then justify that with the "uniqueness part of the definition", which is exactly what the author is trying to prove? Have I misunderstood something?

Comment: NO dimension can be negative so all of them must be zero so he is basically saying that (that's what he meant by each $u_j$ must be $0$.

Comment: Well why can't one $u_j$ cancel another one?

Comment: Because they can't be negative. I mean the number of bases of vector spaces is not a negative number. You can have a basis vector to be completly negative but how many of them you have is non-negative integer quantity.

Comment: It is not a tautology. It is just an easy proof following by the definition of direct sum. It says that by the *definition of the direct sum* there is a *unique* way to write $0$ as the sum $u_{1}+\dots +u_{n}$ where $u_{i} \in U_{i}$. But at the same time we know that $0 \in U_{i},  \forall i$ and $0+\dots +0=0$. If there was also a set of nonzero (or better not all zero) vectors $u_{i}$, $ i=1,\dots, n$, such that $u_{1}+\dots +u_{n}=0$ it would violate uniqueness.

Comment: That makes some sense @m.a.. However, if the unique way of writing $0$ as the sum $u_1+\cdots +u_n$,$\,u_i\in U_i$ is already stated in the definition of the direct sum, what is the point of this proposition? Is it only 'proved' to complete the whole 'if and only if' condition for the proposition (i.e. 'to look nice'/'to be complete')?

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan My guess is the following: I assume that the definition of the direct sum requires that all vectors in $V$ are written uniquely as a sum $u_{1} +\dots+u_{n}$, $u_{i} \in U_{i}$. The proposition, however, says that it suffices to check that for $0$. If it holds for $0$ then it will hold for all points in $V$. Does this sound right/helpful? In other words, the value of the proposition comes in the "if" part; not the "only if" that easily followed from the definition.

Comment: @m.a. Yeah that sounds right. Thanks man!

Comment: @m.a. if you write your comments in an answer, I'd be glad to accept it as an answer.

Comment: @ArturoDonJuan Done. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By the definition of the direct sum, there is a unique way to write $0$ as the sum $u_1+\dots +u_n$, where $u_i \in U_i$. 
But at the same time, we know that $0 \in U_i$ $\forall i$, and $0+\dots+0=0$. 
If there was also a set of nonzero (or better not all zero) vectors $u_i$, $i=1, \dots, n$, such that $u_1+\dots +u_n = 0$ it would violate uniqueness.
This proves the "only if" part for (b), which indeed follows easily from the definition.

Recall, however, that the definition of the direct sum requires that *all* vectors in $V$ are written uniquely as a sum $u_1+\dots +u_n$, $u_i \in U_i$. 
The proposition essentially states that it *suffices* to only check that this property holds for $0$. 
If it holds for $0$ then it will hold for all points in $V$. In other words, the value of the proposition comes in the "if" part; not the "only if" that easily followed from the definition.

Answer (score 0):

The author defines the direct sum here:

> [image]

Note that he says that in a direct sum (by definition), *"each vector in $V$ **can be uniquely represented** in the form above"*.  It is from this that we are able to prove (b).